# Calculus question by using rate of change

Tags: calculus

Question: A rectangular building with the length is 800 meters and the width is 400 meters base is being built. If the volume increase at 1000 meters cube per day, how fast is the height changing when the building is 100 meters high if the length increases at $1.5 $ height meters per day and width increases at square roof of height meters per day?

I thought I did wrong...because of the negative answer....
I got:

$V=HWL$

$\dfrac{dH}{dt}=-0.004999$ meters per day

Thank you for answering my question to all!

Comment: I wonder if you're confusing miles per day with meters per day?  Mixing miles with meters is odd.

Comment: miles per day. Let me re-edit the question. Thank you Michael Hardy:)

Comment: At those sizes we would have to take account of the curvature of the Earth. I'm almost certain all your "miles" should "metres".

Comment: You are right. But this was a senior given question... Let me re-edit it again